# regex expression to get GUIDs from JSON

Tags: java, regex

Hi i need a regex expression in java syntax that will return the list of guids from the following json

```
{"status":0,"StressTest":[{"User":[
{"token":"0F6B271C-3D7B-4473-9B20-67E1B79778FD"},
{"token":"0FC5764C-37F3-4348-8AF9-B6A84EA578E1"},
{"token":"22ADCBA3-13FB-439C-BF0C-F383B87670DB"},
{"token":"22B5D91F-5F49-4F60-9165-5DA5241C0F37"},
{"token":"27D91B27-C2FA-4829-8434-10DF496EF139"},
{"token":"27DDD239-279C-46A1-91C7-19525624A495"}]}]}
```

so i get back just the guids

Thanks for all pointers

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Now that you know it is `JSON`, why are you searching for `Regex` to parse it? Use some JSON Parser.

Comment: i am using it in a foreach loop in jmeter so cant use a json parser. i have tried this "token":"(.+?)" but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with a regular expression, but it would be much better to use a JSON parser. When you still want to use a regular expression, this one should work:

```
[0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{12}
```

At least it works on your test data in http://regexpal.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
String s = "{\"status\":0,\"StressTest\":[{\"User\":["
        + "{\"token\":\"27D91B27-C2FA-4829-8434-10DF496EF139\"}" +
        "{\"token\":\"27DDD239-279C-46A1-91C7-19525624A495\"}]}]}";
String[] a = s.split(".+\\[\\{\"User\":\\[|\\]}\\]}")[1].replaceAll("\"", "").replaceAll("\\{token:", "").split("}");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

output

```
[27D91B27-C2FA-4829-8434-10DF496EF139, 27DDD239-279C-46A1-91C7-19525624A495]
```